# Efficient ways of inserting a new cell into a sorted UITableView?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, nsmutablearray, sorting

I am trying to insert a new cell into a table view where the data is sorted. Is there an easy & efficient way to do this using the API?

The easiest way seems to be insert the new data into an NSMutableArray, sort using a sort descriptor, and call reloadData. This should only redisplay the visible rows, so it doesn't look too bad.

Would it be worthwhile to do a binary search on the data array, insert the data and then insert the cell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really depends on how many rows are in your table. If your table only has around 10 rows, simply adding the data to your `NSMutableArray`, resorting, and reloading the `UITableView` should be just fine.

On the other hand, if your table has hundreds or thousands of rows, you are definitely going to want to do something more efficient. Using a binary search to insert your data into your `NSMutableArray` is a good idea. Then all you have to do is call `UITableView`'s [`insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:) to add the row to the actual table view. No reloading required.